# store and download the excel file in php

Tags: php, excel

please check my coding for create the excel file and download.

```
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");;
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.xls ");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");

        echo "<table style='border: 1px solid red;border-color:red' cellspacing='0'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th style='background-color:yellow;border:1px solid red'>Link id</th><th style='background-color:yellow;border:1px solid red'>Priority</th><th style='background-color:yellow;border:1px solid red'>Year</th><th style='background-color:yellow;border:1px solid red'>Make</th><th style='background-color:yellow;border:1px solid red'>Model</th><th style='background-color:yellow;border:1px solid red'>Input URL</th><th style='background-color:yellow;border:1px solid red'>Changes Found</th><th style='background-color:yellow;border:1px solid red'>Output filename</th><th style='background-color:yellow;border:1px solid red'>No of Changes</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Check how? What doesn't work? (Except that it isn't a real Excel file, but I assume you are aware of that and that is part of the concept)

Comment: @Pekka - "isn't a real Excel file"... These days, I'm no longer surprised by the number of people that believe an HTML or CSV with a .xls extension really is an Excel file, or who think that PHP automagically converts their HTML/CSV to a real Excel file when they define the content type in their headers.

Comment: use one Content-Type header rather than three (application/vnd.ms-excel is the correct mime type for a real Excel file), and you only need one semi-colon (;) at the end of each line

Comment: I'm also surprised by people who think that multiple content-type headers will work. Look, the download's a barbie doll AND a monster truck AND a snowball, all at the same time. wowzers. Cargo cult programming...

Answer (score 2):

Use an external library like [PHP Excel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to create excel file and then send it to download.  Is the easiest way and you don't have to reinvent the wheel. I've used this library and is very good. Alternately you think can use [COM](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) functions to do the same thing, although I never used them.

Comment: +1 for the only really proper solution (although I can see how the simplicity of building a table is tempting.)

Comment: One of these days, I'll create an HTML reader for PHPExcel that can be used to convert HTML to XLS/XLSX in much the same way Excel can do it. That will allow users to build their HTML tables and export it as a real Excel file

Comment: did you mean for your link to PHP Excel to point to the PHP COM pages?

Comment: @Mark Baker. thanks. It was an error, I had both links with the same number.

Answer (score 1):

If you write an excelfile with an `<table>`, excel will send a warning to the user, trying to open the excel-file, that the file doesn't seem to be a regular file, and if they want to open it anyway.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bx8ZY.png <- Image of the warning